# Cannot install gulp and bower in a Nave virtual environment on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, shell

I installed Npm according to the guide from [Beginners Guide to Node.js: Installing Node on MacOS Sierra](https://www.codementor.io/mercurial/how-to-install-node-js-on-macos-sierra-mphz41ekk) and now I am required to install bower and gulp according to the following instructions:

Next create a new Nave environment automatically according to the setting in .naverc. The version of Node in our server is 4.6.0, so maybe better to follow it. This command will also load this environment with a sub-shell.

```
nave auto
```

NOTE: Later you can exit the sub-shell with exit or ^D.

Then Inside the sub-shell run these to install npm local packages and 2 npm global packages, bower and gulp. NOTE: If you've previously installed node/bower, run these before running the below install commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
rm -rf client/static/bower_components/
```

Install commands:

```
npm install --global bower
npm install --global gulp-cli
npm install
bower install
```

................"

When I enter nave subshell with nave auto, there is no nvm installed inside. If I install and then leave and re-enter, again there is no nvm and all the subsequent commands fail.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the same command that is **npm install -g bower** , from windows powershell as administrator.

It worked for me.